# session_set_cookie_params - domain parameters correct value to use

Tags: php, session, cookies

Have seen the usage for [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) domain parameter as null like below.

```
session_set_cookie_params('604800', '/', null, true, true);
```

Consulting the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) it suggests that for domain:

> session.cookie_domain string
>   session.cookie_domain specifies the domain to set in the session cookie. Default is none at all.....

Thus enquiring if

> null

is a right value to use here or should actually

> none

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you made a mistake with a translation. If the attribute-value is empty, the behavior is undefined according to cookies specification.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2.3

If you want to leave this param empty you should use **null** or **''**. You can't set 'none' for this purpose.